# What is the definiteness of this function?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, positive-definite

I have this function:

$$\frac{1}{2}\left ( x^{2}+4y^2 \right )e^{-\left ( x^{2}+4y^2 \right )}$$

I might be wrong, but it is the product of two functions: the first one is positive definite (positive eigenvalues), while the exponential one is negative definite (negative eigenvalues). The answer tells me that this function is globally positive definite. But isn't the product of a positive definite function and a negative definite function a negative definite function? Where I'm wrong here?

Comment: Is $e^{-\left ( x^{2}+4y^2 \right )}$ negative definite?

Comment: I guess the exponential function is negative definite because it features the same first function but with opposite sign.

Comment: What specific definition are you using for the function being positive or negative definite?

Comment: Sign of eigenvalues of the matrix derived from the quadratic form.

Comment: Or the sign of the upper left determinants of the same matrix. There are many options, these two I mentioned are the simplest.

Comment: (A) In one Definition, Positive Definite == $f(x,y)>0$ ( Positive for all $(x,y)$ ) , and both Parts are Non-Negative here. (B) If $(1)^2+(x)^2+(y)^2$ is Positive, can we conclude that $(-1)^2+(-x)^2+(-y)^2$ is Negative because we changed the Signs ?? NO !! (C) Given function actually has Semi-Positive Part & Positive Part (D) Overall it is Semi-Positive, because $f(0,0)=0$ !

Comment: Hello Prem, thank you for your contribution, but I'd like to point out that $\left (-x \right )^{2} \neq -x^{2}$. Graphically speaking, the exponential function is far from being a "bowl shaped" function like the first one, which is the typical shape of a positive definite function.

Comment: Just check  [Examples of positive definite kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_kernel) in wikipedia: Entry "Gaussian Kernel"

Comment: [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function#:~:text=Two-dimensional%20Gaussian%20function,-3d%20plot%20of&text=In%20two%20dimensions%2C%20the%20power,Gaussian%20will%20always%20be%20ellipses.) "In two dimensions, the power to which e is raised in the Gaussian function is any negative-definite quadratic form."

Comment: You are mistaken by the wording of Gaussian function : "the **POWER** to which e is raised in the Gaussian function **IS** any negative-definite quadratic form" ; that is ; the "POWER" is Negative, while Gaussian function itself is not Negative !! The "POWER" is Eg $-(x^2+4y^2)$ which is Negative because $(x^2+4y^2)$ is POSITIVE ; Overall, Gaussian function is not Negative !!

Comment: @Prem Ok. I understand. Let's suppose what you say is true (and it probably is). How can I prove that the Gaussian function is not negative? I simply thought that this function would be negative because its power is negative. The only way I can prove the power is negative is by calculating the eigenvalues of the matrix of the quadratic form. What about ALL the Gaussian function (exp included)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In One **ViewPoint**, a function $P(x) , P(x,y) , P(x,y,z) ...$ is **Positive Definite** (or Positive Semi-Definite) when it is **Positive** (or Non-Negative) when evaluated at all values of $x , y , z ...$

In your case, :
$$P(x,y)= (x^2+4y^2)$$

$$f(x,y)= P(x,y)(e^{-P(x,y)})$$

Here $P(x,y)$ is 0 at (0,0) & Positive elsewhere; Hence it is **Positive Semi-Definite**.
The **Power Part** $-P(x,y)$ is 0 at (0,0) & Negative elsewhere; Hence it is **Negative Semi-Definite**.

Then $e^{-P(x,y)}$ is 1 at (0,0) & between 1 & 0 elsewhere; It can be considered **Positive Definite**.

**End-Product** is 0 at (0,0) & Positive elsewhere; Hence it can be considered **Positive Semi-Definite**.

Comment: I accepted the answer only because it is the only one that resembles a proper answer, but I'm not 100% sure about it. The first function is positive definite (except 0,0, but 0,0 is the reference point so it is alright), and the Gaussian one may be positive definite only IF it is not equal to 0 somewhere, otherwise it is positive semi-definite. In other words, it is definite positive if it tends to 0 asymptotically without ever reaching it, otherwise it is positive semi-definite. In the first case, the overall function is (globally) positive definite, in the other is positive semi-definite.

Comment: (A) In your Q, you said that Exponential Part is Negative ; I have shown that it is not Negative. (B) You said "Positive times Negative = Negative" and asked where you were wrong : The answer that it is "Positive times Positive = Positive" in this case. (C) You also said "The answer tells me that this function is globally positive definite" ; Which textbook is this ? Can you copy-paste (or snapshot) (1) the Question in the textbook (2) the Definition of Positiveness in the textbook & (3) the answer in the textbook ? That will help clarify the situation !